# When does $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(q(x,0))=\frac{\partial q}{\partial x}(x,0)$?

Tags: functions, partial-differential-equations, self-learning

I'm working on a question from a past exam paper (Mathematics BSc, second-year module in differential equations, unpublished). Here's a paraphrase of the question:

> Consider the first-order PDE $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+V\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=0,\tag{1}$$
> where $V>0$ is a constant. The general solution [found in part of the question] is $u(x,t)=g(x-Vt)$, where $g$ is an arbitrary function.
>
> Under a certain condition [proved as part of the question; I don't think it's needed here], $(1)$ is satisfied by $$u(x,t)=\frac{\partial q}{\partial t}-V\frac{\partial q}{\partial x},\tag{2}$$
> where $q(x,t)$ is another function.
>
> The function $q$ satisfies the initial conditions $$q(x,0)=\frac{1}{1+x^4},\;\;\frac{\partial q}{\partial t}(x,0)=0.$$
>
> Find the solution of $(1)$ for the $u$ given in $(2$) [I think "subject to these initial conditions" is implied].

For part of the solution, the answer booklet has,

> At time $t=0$, $$u(x,0)=-V\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{1}{1+x^4}\right)=\frac{4Vx^3}{1+x^4}=g(x).$$

This seems to use $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(q(x,0))$ where I would expect to see $\frac{\partial q}{\partial x}(x,0)$. In general, these aren't the same, right? I also get $-V\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{1}{1+x^4}\right)=\frac{4Vx^3}{(1+x^4)^2}$. Could someone help me understand what's gone wrong?

Comment: those are just two notations for the same thing

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Presumably you'll agree this sort of equality doesn't hold in the univariate case? For instance, let $f(x)=x^2$; then $\frac{df}{dx}(1)=(2x)(1)=2\cdot1=2\neq0=\frac{d}{dx}(1)=\frac{d}{dx}(1^2)=\frac{d}{dx}(f(1))$. So in general, is a partial evaluation of a partial derivative of a multivariate function equal to the corresponding partial derivative of the corresponding partial evaluation?

Comment: first, this issue has nothing to do with several variables; the $y$ above is just irrelevant. In your example you say something about $\frac d{dx}(f(1))$ but there's no $\frac d{dx}(f(x))$ in sight. But I see your point. When people write $\frac d{dx}(f(x))$ they actually mean the derivastive of the function $f$, not the derivative of the _value_ $f(x)$. Hence it's a bad notation

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich The problem doesn't seem to me to be just notational. We're given $q(x,0)$ so we can find $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(q(x,0))$, which is what's used in the solution; but we have no information about $\frac{\partial q}{\partial x}(x,0)$, which is what seems to me to be needed to find $u(x,0)$ in terms of its partial derivatives at time $t=0$.

Comment: Edit: "in terms of the partial derivatives of $q$"

Comment: I understand you are trying an answer to: $\lim_{y\to 0} \frac{\partial q(x,y)}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\lim_{y\to 0} q(x,y) $. Isn't it?

Comment: @Davius I think that's different from what I'm asking.