# Given $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, does $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,0)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(f(x,0))$ always hold?

Tags: functions, partial-derivative

Prompted by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4462635/when-does-frac-partial-partial-xqx-0-frac-partial-q-partial-xx-0) question. I can't immediately think of a counterexample to the proposition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should start by claryfing what do you mean by those symbols.

In particular the notation on right hand side seems a bit odd, since $\gamma(x)=f(x,0)$ is a function of the variable $x$ only.
I would rewrite the right hand side as $\frac{d}{dx} f(x,0)$.

Then the equality holds by definition, since for any $x_{0}$ you have  $\frac{\partial f }{\partial x} (x_{0},0) = \lim _{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x_{0}+t,0)-f(x_{0},0)}{t}= \frac{d}{dx}f(x_{0},0)$

Edit: there's still a small (but common I would say) abuse of notation in writing $\frac{d}{dx}f(x_{0},0)$ when we mean $[\frac{d}{dx}f(x,0)](x_{0})$, since we are conflating the derivative as a function with its value in the point $x_0$.

If you wanted to be super fussy about it you could write $\frac{d\gamma}{dx}(x_{0})$ or $[\frac{d}{dx}f(x,0)](x_{0})$ instead.
In practice it doesen't make sense to use such a cumbersome notation when it's pretty clear what we mean by $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,0)$.